# Proof that $y = |x|$ is not regular smooth

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives, solution-verification, parametrization, smooth-functions

I've been studying vector calculus, and I came across the notion of regular smoothness.

In particular, the textbook I am using claims that $y = |x|$ has no regular smooth parametrization. No proof of this fact is given.

This is intuitively obvious to me; here is why:

Given any parametrization of this curve, the derivative at $(0,0)$ must be the zero vector. For suppose we are given
$$
r(t) = \langle x(t), |x(t)| \rangle 
$$

Then we get that $r'(t)$ does not exist if $x'(t) \neq 0$, because then the directional limits would disagree on sign. Thus the only way for $x'(t)$ to be defined is to be the zero vector. Thus this curve has no regular parametrization.

Would this constitute a proof in this scenario? -- Furthermore, how can I generalize this to determine which classes of curves are regular smooth. For example, are 'cusps' the only issue?

Comment: "Regular smoothness" is equivalent to the existence of a tangent line to the curve at each point. (Even though a cusp appears to have a tangent line, the curve must locally be a graph of a differentiable function with domain that tangent line; the cusp fails the "vertical line test.")

Comment: @TedShifrin could you elaborate on the cusp failing the "vertical line test"? I'm confused as to how I must understand the notion that the cusp's apparent tangent line is ill defined

Comment: The potential tangent line to the cusp $y^2=x^3$ at the origin is the $x$-axis. But this curve is certainly not the graph of a function of $x$, smooth or not.